# Finding the order of the zero of the function $f(z)= z^5-3z^4+8z^2-9z+3$ at $1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Finding the order of the zero of the function $f(z)= z^5-3z^4+8z^2-9z+3$

There is a simple zero at $z=1$ as $f(0)=0$

Taking the derivative $f'(1)=0$ also so the function should have more than just a simple zero.

Redefining it $f(z)=(z-1)^3(z^2-3)$

From this the function has a zero of order $3$ at $z=1$.

Is this complete?

Can anyone help me solve this question. Thanks any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

For any function $f(z)$ if you factor it into terms $(z-z_i)^{n_i}$, the number $n_i\in \mathbb{N}$ is the correct multiplicity of the zero $z_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have factored out $(z-1)^3$ and noticed that $z^2-3$ is not $0$ at $z=1$, you know the order is $3$.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't redefine $f$, you factored it.  And the factorization shows that $1$ is a root of multiplicity $3$.